# Should I answer my own question if the answer was from someone else on another site?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked this question: [Why is my Pico-8 cartridge larger than 32K?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44348194/why-is-my-pico-8-cartridge-larger-than-32k), and someone pointed out in the comments that I should ask the question on a specific forum. I did that, and got two solid replies at [Lexaloffles forum](https://www.lexaloffle.com/bbs/?tid=29427)

I added the link to that answer in the comments, but I would like the question to be resolved. I am wondering what is the best thing to do? Should I copy the answers, and credit the two who helped me? Or should I just leave the question be?

Comment: You can always put a cite and a link into your answer.

Comment: There is *one* ideal person to delete an off-topic question at SO.  Can do it with a single vote, does not require any privileges or rep, doesn't require an army of volunteers to get the job done.  It is you.

Comment: I don't know anything about that. But isn't it off topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking there is nothing wrong with quoting an answer from a different source, linking to it and properly crediting the original authors of the answer. You also have the possibility to make the answer a community wiki in case you don't have anything to add to it yourself.

In this particular case though, the question is not on-topic for SO as it's not really about programming:

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

So I'd recommend to just delete the SO question and be happy that you've found the answer you were looking for in the forum.